# Running OTEL agent as windows service is not working

Tags: grafana, loki

Want to run Otel collecor agent as Windows services. So downloaded latest windows release package and run the following command to create service and start the service.

```
sc.exe create otelcol displayname= otelcol start= delayed-auto
binPath=
"C:\Users\admin\otelcol-contrib_0.94.0_windows_386\otelcol-contrib.exe
--config C:\Users\admin\Core-Otel.yaml" sc.exe start otelcol
```

but the service is not started and resulted with error on event viewer as

> The otelcol service terminated with the following error: An exception occurred in the service when handling the control request.

Otel collector agent version: 0.94.0

OS: Windows servers

Could any one point the right direction to deploy the Otel agent as windows service ?

**Updated command with quotes for folder paths:**

```
sc.exe create otelcol displayname= otelcol start= delayed-auto
binPath=
\""C:\Users\admin\otelcol-contrib_0.94.0_windows_386\otelcol-contrib.exe\"
 --config \"C:\Users\admin\Core-Otel.yaml\"" 
sc.exe description "Otelcol"
sc.exe start otelcol
```

Now able to run as windows service.

Comment: That product is a million miles away from being suitable for a production environment.

Comment: maybe nssm is the way you want, but i would test first, if the command you run, works without the Service part. moreover, running a software within a user folder that should be used by the system is imho not a good idea.

Comment: Based on this discussion https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/issues/6433, otel already have the implementation but still getting the error.

Comment: Updated the commands with quotes worked for me. sc.exe create otelcol displayname= otelcol start= delayed-auto
binPath=
\""C:\Users\admin\otelcol-contrib_0.94.0_windows_386\otelcol-contrib.exe\"
 --config \"C:\Users\admin\Core-Otel.yaml\""